# 502 Proxy Error - MeteorJS on Apache

Tags: apache, proxy, meteor, centos

I am new to Meteor, and I have an existing server that is hosting a few websites (CentOS).  I use Apache to serve the sites and wanted to have a Meteor app running on a subdomain.

Here is what I have for the Meteor site in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.subdomain.domain.net
    ServerAlias subdomain.domain.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_meteor_directory/testapp
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000

</VirtualHost>
```

I also have this at the bottom of my httpd.conf file:

```
<Proxy *>
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://localhost:3000/$1$2
```

I set the app to run on port 3000 and when I try to hit it in the browser (subdomain.domain.net) I get these 502 errors:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName meteorapp.example.com
 ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

then reload the server

Comment: I tried this and am no longer getting the 502 errors, but instead it just takes forever and finally gives me a 503 :(